# retrieve field value of dataset in customizer class

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Inside a subreport, I have a bar chart which uses a `Dataset1` (3 fields retrieved from the db). I have customized this bar chart with the help of a customizer class. Now my question is, how to get the value of field (which is part of the chart dataset) in the customizer class

I tried using

`String city = (String) getFieldValue("city");`

But this says no such field found. The `getFieldValue()` only returns those fields defined at the subreport level and not at the `Dataset1` level.

Comment: Are you using hibernate/sql and java or just ireport and no java? Can you explain your set up more.

Comment: I am using sql with a customizer class in Java in Jaspersoft studio v5.6